# How to disable the document well in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, tabs, ide, visual-studio-2015

The document well is the feature in VS 2015 that closes a tab automatically when you switch to a different tab, unless you click the "Keep Open" button in the tab.

I find this very annoying, because often I will open a tab during debugging only to have it disappear after which I have to go hunting for the file again.

Is there a way to disable this feature, i.e. to keep all tabs open permanently, the way VS 2013 did?

I've looked in Tools\Options, and also did a quick web search, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck the **Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab** option:

[image]

Comment: This worked in VS2013, in VS2015 the preview Tab still gets opened even though I unchecked this option.